# Заполнение таблиц в MS Word посредством C#

Tags: c#, visual-basic, ms-word

Суть проблемы: есть документ *MS Word*, который содержит несколько таблиц и необходимо их программно заполнять. Я могу обращаться и работать только с одной таблицей посредством кода типа:

```
  var Wref = this.Application.ActiveDocument;
  Word.Range x = this.Application.Selection.Range;
  Wref.Tables.Add(rng, 4, 4, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
  Wref.Tables[1].Cell(1, 1).Range.InsertAfter("v");
```

Однако, ко второй таблице подобным способом я обратиться не могу. При попытке сделать что-либо типа `Wref.Tables[2].Cell(1, 1).Range.InsertAfter("v");`  выдает ошибку и пишет что требуемое семейство не найдено.

Я читал в *MSDN* о программировании в *MS Word* и предполагаю что, возможно, следует использовать "понятие" **paragraph** или как-то указать другой диапазон *Range*. Но я не понял как правильно это сделать, и вообще я не до конца понимаю каким образом располагаются таблицы в документе и чем они отличаются.

Буду благодарен за разъяснение проблемы или пример кода, решающий данную проблему. (Тип языка программирования не важен, но мне кажется, проще всего эта проблема решается на *C#* / *Visual Basic*)

Comment: Неплохой способ понять, как работать с объектной моделью Word - записывать макросы. Если не понимаете почему ваш код не работает,  и документация не помогает - запустите запись макроса и сделайте руками те же или примерно те же действия, что собираетесь делать программно. Когда макрос записан, вы можете открыть редактор VBA и посмотреть код макроса. Код будет несколько  отличаться от того, что вам в итоге придется написать на .Net. Но он будет работать с теми же объектами, поэтому суть должна быть той же.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, какое именно семейство не найдено `Tables[2]` или `Cell(1,1)` или еще какое-то? Я к тому, что может стоит эту вторую таблицу `Tables[2]` добавить в документ перед тем как обращаться к ее ячейкам.

Answer (score 1):

> есть документ MS Word, который содержит несколько таблиц и необходимо 
>     их программно заполнять.
>   Wref.Tables[1].Cell(1, 1).Range.InsertAfter("v");
>   ко второй таблице подобным способом я обратиться не могу

тут [1] - это обращение к первой таблице.

в Interop.Word для обращения к элементам надо указывать порядковый номер.
т.е. для обращение ко второй таблице укажите [2].