# Как сделать запись текста разного формата в word документ из приложения C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

Не могу въехать в запись текста разного формата в word документ из приложения C#. Вот такой код имею:

```
Word._Application word_app = new Word.Application();
word_app.Visible = true;
object missing = Type.Missing;
Word._Document word_doc = word_app.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
Word.Paragraph para = word_doc.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
para.Range.Text = "Chrysanthemum Curve";
```

Результатом его выполнения является открытие word, и запись в первую строчку Chrysanthemum Curve. Суть проблемы в том что я не могу понять как добавить следующую строчку.

Добавление второго:

```
Word.Paragraph para2=word_doc.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
para2.Range.Text = "Text 2";
```

Обращение на прямую не изменяет текущий и не добавляет новый блок текста.

```
word_doc.Paragraphs[0].Range.Text = "Text 1";
word_doc.Paragraphs[1].Range.Text = "Text 2";
```

Comment: Ну так вы пишете в параграф, который, вполне вероятно, является одной большой строкой. Попробуйте новый параграф добавить.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я пробовал, не получается. Текст нового заменят старый.

Comment: @Eugen: Покажите код, как вы добавили второй paragraph. Есть шанс, что вы пишете в тот же объект.

Comment: @Eugen: «Не работает» писать нельзя, вы же программист! Что значит «не срабатывает»? Не компилируется? Бросает исключение? Опишите ваши шаги, что происходит, и что вы ожидаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообщем дело обстоит так:

Изначально создается документ.

```
Word._Application word_app = new Word.Application();
word_app.Visible = true;
object missing = Type.Missing;
Word._Document word_doc = word_app.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

К нему мы добавляем блок текста.

```
Word.Paragraph para = word_doc.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
```

причем сколько бы раз мы не делали

```
para = word_doc.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
```

количество блоков будет увеличиваться, а para ссылаться на первый блок.

допустим чтобы добавить 3 блока, необходимо 4 раза вызвать

```
 word_doc.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
 word_doc.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
 word_doc.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
 word_doc.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
```

а после обращаться к каждому по отдельности, причем нумерация как я понял начинается с 1.

```
word_doc.Paragraphs[1].Range.Text = "Text 1";
word_doc.Paragraphs[2].Range.Text = "Text 2";
word_doc.Paragraphs[3].Range.Text = "Text 3";
```

Comment: _"нумерация как я понял начинается с 1."_ -- да, надо указывать порядковые номера. другой пример - [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474180/196972)

Answer (score -1):

Если сделать `para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();`, то `para` будет ссылаться на новый параграф.